# ¿Cómo puedo limpiar un cadena en java?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8

tengo un programa hecho en java que me recorre un archivo ese archivo posee las siguientes lineas por ejemplo.

```
11222ytygygy.jkjkjj,ooiin899

222huhhh.ppok,oio0.okok87

6te6hu82nw9.je8e82.0923m
```

y asi sucesivamente
lo que necesito es como puedo quitar las letras y remplazar las comas por puntos y si aparecen mas puntos en la linea solo dejar uno

He estado utilizando el replaceAll pero no se si sea lo mejor o hay mejor forma
aqui lo que he utilizado

```
public static String reemplazar(String cadena, String busqueda, String reemplazo) {
    return cadena.replaceAll(busqueda, reemplazo);
}
```

este metodo es el que utilizo mas que todo para hacer lo del remplazo lo que hago es meter en un for y comparar con un array donde tengo un diccionario

Comment: lo que trato de hacer es quitar todos los caracteres que aparecen hay, pero no e podido hacer eso, lo que e tratado es meter toda la linea y hacer una comparacion con replaceAll pero no e logrado. y a lo que me refiero es que como en el ejemplo 6te6hu82nw9.je8e82.0923m hay dos puntos, y hay que quitar uno y solo se deja uno

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usando tu metodo `reemplazar` le paso la expresion regular:

> `"(?i)[a-z]"`

Que signfica:

```
 - (?i) -> sin importar mayusculas o minusculas
 - [a-z] -> letras de la "a" a la "z"

String cadena = "11222ytygygy.jkjkjj,ooiin899";
String sinLetras = reemplazar(cadena,"(?i)[a-z]","");
```

Output

> ```
> "11222.,899"
> ```

---

Luego cambiamos las comas por puntos:

```
String sinLetrasNiComas = reemplazar(sinLetras,",",".");
```

Output:

> ```
> "11222..899"
> ```

---

Y como ultimo paso tenemos que eliminar los puntos repetidos dejando el primero.

Para ello primero identifico la posicion del primero con `indexOf`

```
int k = sinLetrasNiComas.indexOf(".");  
System.out.println(k);
```

Output:

> ```
> 5
> ```

Y cogemos el primer cacho del String, hasta ese punto (`"11222."`) y el string de despues (`".899"`) le reemplazamos los puntos por `empty string ""`

**Aviso importante** `->` Como `replaceAll` se le pasa una expresion regular, si le pasas `"."` para que quite los puntos, va a quitarlo todo porque esa expresion regular significa "cualquier cosa". Por eso le paso `"\\.+"` que significa "quita cualquier ocurrencia de 1 o más puntos".
Con `","` no habia problema porque esa expresion no tiene significado y 
funcionaría como un `replace` normal.

```
String sinLetrasSoloUnPunto = sinLetrasNiComas.substring(0,k+1) + reemplazar(sinLetrasNiComas.substring(k),"\\.+", "");
```

---

Dejando todo:

```
System.out.println(sinLetrasSoloUnPunto);
```

Output:

> ```
> "11222.899"
> ```

---

**[DEMO](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUXRDX2hnbzRzTFk)**

Answer (score 2):

Para borrar las letras de la cadena lo que haría sería lo siguiente:

```
String cadena = "11222ytygygy.jkjkjj,ooiin899";   /*cadena vieja*/
String nuevaCadena=""; /*cadena con solo números*/ 

for(i=0;i<cadena.length;i++){
     int letra=(int) cadena[i];
     if(letra<=65 || letra>=122){
        nuevaCadena+=cadena[i]; 
     } 
}
```

Aquí lo he he hecho ha sido pasar cada carácter de la cadena a Ascii, y sabiendo que en Ascii el número 65 es la letra A y el número 122 es la letra z, comprobamos que dicho carácter no esté entre 65 y 122 en Ascii para controlar que no sea ninguna letra. También puedes comprobar que sea un número (en Ascii desde el 48 al 57).

Para reemplazar las comas por puntos haría otro *for*, pero no he entendido muy bien cuales son los puntos que quieres reemplazar y cuales no. Existen varios métodos para reemplazar carácteres en Java, entre ellos el *replace()* normal, el *replaceAll()*, y el *replaceFirst()* que solo reemplaza el primer carácter que tú le digas.

Comment: Me complace que quieras aportar, pero no es correcto lo que propones! ¿Cómo puedes acceder a `cadena[i]` si `cadena` es un `String`. Corrige el código, tiene errores de compilación!